# Best way to prevent user from accesing data

Tags: java, storing-data

So, I've been practicing game development in java. Now I'm trying to save user's progress by putting data in a file. But if I put it just into a text file, obviously it's going to be easily accessible. What would be the best way to store/hash data like for example "current level, attack power etc".

Thanks.

Comment: Might be better to ask of [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is going to be a vague answer.

If you simply just don't want it to be a text file, you can write a binary file using binary serialization of the language you are using.

As a second step, you may consider encrypting your files.

But, no matter what you do, or how hard you try, as long as all the data are stored on the client then your users may still be able to alter them.

If you don't want to store all the info remotely due to space constraints, you can store just the file hash remotely and verify that it has not been tampered with.

Comment: Thanks, would it be ok if i used like a random hash + integer data in an MD5 hash, something like a password storage.

Comment: Yes, you can add salt if you really want, but I'd assume that a very limited amount of lookup tables exist for something as complex as your whole save file :) (in other words, the random part may be unnecessary). Remember that encryption means you'll have to store your key somewhere, possibly on the server side.

Comment: You are welcome. But, if I may give an unsolicited suggestion, if you are starting playing around with game development, don't worry about things as security of your application, but rather on learning more about physics engines, rendering etc. Triple A titles mess up their anti-cheating softwares daily, it's a lot of wasted effort of your energies to focus on those at such an early stage :)

Comment: @VelisaPetricevic, if the answer satisfies you, can you tick it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt and store the date in a text file.Encryption will prevent the user from modifying it.

Comment: But then you need to find a way to hide the encryption key.

Comment: Yup you can store the password in code or use some logic in code to generate it..I know it is not safe and any hacker can hack it..But I think if the data is just about levels/scores you can store...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) which is a file-based DB. It supports [encryption](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) as well as many operating systems, easy to install and use!

Read more about it [here](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html).

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way of accomplishing this is to use serialization. It allows you to directly take your java object and save it in its current state. A good tutorial of this is at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/

The only way to easily read and change this data is if you have access to the java class that created it.